# Local Scheduled Push Notification not working In Release mode?

Tags: react-native

I used  "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1", It works very well in debug but notifications do not display in release apk, and (my android version: 12)

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: const handleClockInNotification = (title, message) => {
    createChannel();
    const date = Date.now();
    const dateNew = new Date(timeIn);
    console.log("Clock In Time Is============>", timeIn);
    // console.log("Daate1 =============>", date);
    // console.log("DatNEW =============>", dateNew.getTime());
    const fiveMinutesBefore = new Date(date - 1 * 60 * 1000);
    PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
      channelId: "specialid",
      title: title,
      message: message,
      date: fiveMinutesBefore,
      color: "blue",
    });
  };

Comment: const createChannel = () => {
    PushNotification.createChannel({
      channelId: "specialid",
      channelName: "Special messasge",
      channelDescription: "Notification for special message",
      importance: 4,
      vibrate: true,
    });
  };

Comment: In debug works fine but in realse apk it does not show notification what's the issue? I used react-native": "0.68.2"

Comment: I've add answer please check it and tell me if it's work for you :D

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

React native push notifications have an issue if the Android target SDK is > 30 you can check this issue in [github](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/2310)

To fix it you will need to patch the library using this patch:

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android/src/main/java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/modules/RNPushNotificationHelper.java b/node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android/src/main/java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/modules/RNPushNotificationHelper.java
index ad3527b..447a540 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android/src/main/java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/modules/RNPushNotificationHelper.java
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android/src/main/java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/modules/RNPushNotificationHelper.java
@@ -455,8 +455,13 @@ public class RNPushNotificationHelper {
 
             int notificationID = Integer.parseInt(notificationIdString);
 
-            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationID, intent,
-                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
+            PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
+            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
+                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
+            }
+            else {
+                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
+            }
 
             NotificationManager notificationManager = notificationManager();
```

This solution is already on [github](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/2310).

Comment: I try above solution but it didn't work in realse apk.

Comment: Can you open logcat and check if there' an error fires when the local notification scheduled?

Comment: I didn't check properly, sorry It works properly, Thank you so much.